# Wordpress child theme css does not override parent css

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I am using mies-child theme but the problem is that I cannot see the css changes affect my website.

Here's what my child style.css looks like:

```
/*
Theme Name: Mies Child
Theme URI: http://pixelgrade.com/demos/mies
Author: PixelGrade Team
Author URI: http://pixelgrade.com
Template: mies
Description: MIES is a front line parallax Architecture WordPress Theme prized for allowing you to present your activity within a delightful and captivating experience. It's perfect for a full range of presentations and portfolio projects of designers, architects or photographers.
License: Themeforest Split Licence
License URI: -
Text Domain: mies_txtd
Domain Path: /languages/
Tags: white, light, dark, responsive-layout, custom-colors, custom-header, custom-menu, featured-image-header, featured-images, full-width-template, theme-options, translation-ready
*/
```

This is my child functions.php file:

```
<?php
/*
 * ===== Theme Translation =====
 * Load the translations from the child theme if present
 */
add_action( 'before_wpgrade_core', 'mies_child_theme_setup' );
function mies_child_theme_setup() {
    load_child_theme_textdomain( 'mies_txtd', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );
}

/**
 * ===== Loading Resources =====
 * Add all the extra static resources of the child theme - right now only the style.css file
 */

function mies_child_enqueue_styles() {
    // Here we are adding the child style.css while still retaining all of the parents assets (style.css, JS files, etc)
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mies-child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array('wpgrade-main-style') //make sure the the child's style.css comes after the parents so you can overwrite rules
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mies_child_enqueue_styles' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You tried to add the **`$handle`** of your parent' enqueued style `wpgrade-main-style` as a dependency **`$deps`** for your child enqueue script when the parent's style has not even been enqueued yet.

Retrieve your parent style using **`get_template_directory_uri()`** first and enqueue it followed by retrieving your child styles using **`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`** and enqueue it adding the parent as a dependency **`$deps`** in your child enqueue script like this:

```js
function mies_child_styles() { 
    
    // enqueue parent
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpgrade-main-style', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . '/style.css', array(  );
   
    // enqueue child
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mies-child-style', trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('wpgrade-main-style') );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mies_child_styles' );
```

Comment: I use the proposed code but without have the expected result. Also, wp-admin panel stoped working.

Comment: @arismrk Hmm. Can you try wrapping your `get_template` sections with `trailingslashit()` as shown in the above edited code and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
// Queue parent style followed by child/customized style
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles', PHP_INT_MAX);

function theme_enqueue_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' 
);
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
'/styles/child-style.css', array( 'parent-style' ) );
}
```

Check these things also

1. PHP_INT_MAX as a priority so that this runs last.

Answer (score 0):

i did like this in my project.

```
    function mies_child_enqueue_styles() {
        //enqueue parent styles
        wp_enqueue_style('parent-theme', get_template_directory_uri() .'/style.css');

        // enqueue child styles
        wp_enqueue_style('child-theme', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/style.css', 
        array('parent-theme'));
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mies_child_enqueue_styles');
```